# JQuery not calling HttpPost method on my controller. How can I fix this, or what could be going wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a special case where I need to have a grid with an "Add New Record" row, that exists within an MVC form.

Since I can't submit the new record details, without submitting the entire form, I decided to make the record submit button call a Javascript method that should POST the data to a method on my controller.  In short, here is an example of what I'm doing.  The code below is copy-and-pasted from my project, with only minor modifications for brevity.

```
...
<table>
CODE HERE FOR MY GRID...
</table>
...
<input class="data_field" id="MainSession_Name" type="text" />
<input class="data_field" id="MainSession_Type" type="text" />
<button id="btnAddMainSession" class="button" onclick="SubmitMainSession()" type="button">Add Session</button>
...
<script>
    var SubmitMainSession = function()
    {
        var data = {
            Name: $('MainSession_Name').val(),
            RecType: $('MainSession_Type').val(),
        };

        $.post(
            {


                url: "/Session/Add",
                data: data,
                callback: function(res, status)
                {
                    if (res !== "OK")
                        alert("There was a problem processing the request. " + res);
                    else
                        location.reload(true);
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

My intent is simple.  After the user enters new details for a session, they will click on the `Add Session` button.  JQuery will make a POST request passing my data to my page controller.

Here is an abbreviated variation of my controller:

```
    //Index that initially loads the data.
    public ActionResult Index(int id = -1)
    {
        SessionModel sm = new SessionModel(id);
        sm.CanEdit = true;
        return View(sm);
    }

    //The containing model manages a HUGE form, 
    //across multiple BootStrap.js tabs.  We save 
    //all other, non-sub-record related deets here.
    public ActionResult Submit(SessionModel model)
    {
        model.Save();
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

    //Since there are multiple grids, I need to 
    //have a way to add new Session records.
    //This is my first attempt at trying to 
    //create a POST method on my controller.
    [HttpPost]
    public string Add(AddSessionObject data)
    {
        //If I can ever get here, I'll save the data.
        return "OK";
    }

    public class AddSessionObject
    {
        public string Name;
        public string RecType;
    }
```

What I'm experiencing is that when I make the $.post(...) call in JQuery, MVC always calls the Index(...) method, rather than the Add(...) method.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open up your browser dev tools and see whether it is making an ajax call

Comment: @Shyju, interesting, the browser is, in fact, calling "/Session/Index".  Why?!

Comment: Specifically, this is what I'm seeing in Chrome for the Network request: `http://localhost:49684/Session/Index/[object%20Object]`

Comment: What's the http response code next to the network request?  Is it 200 or 301?

Comment: @nixkuroi `200`.  This is returned after it hits the breakpoint in the controller, on the `Index(...)` method, and returns to the browser.

Comment: Check to see if it hits a breakpoint under submit first.  I suspect it's going there first, then redirecting to index after.

Comment: Using ajax to post data and then just doing a `location.reload()` is pointless. You would be better off just doing a normal submit and redirect in the POST method. The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, so if you want to use it to improve performance, then have your method return a partial view of the newly added item (or json) and update the existing DOM in the success callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this syntax:

```
var data = {
  Name: $('MainSession_Name').val(),
  RecType: $('MainSession_Type').val(),
};

$.post("/Session/Add", data, function(res, status) {
  if (res !== "OK")
    alert("There was a problem processing the request. " + res);
  else
    location.reload(true);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thank you.  I see the issue now.  Simple JQuery syntax issue. :/